# How to get environment variable in 8.3 format?

Tags: vba

I have a simple Sub like this:

```
Private Sub Command90_Click()
    Dim Perc As String

    Perc = Environ("onedrivecommercial")
    Perc = "wscript " & Perc & "\DATABA~1\script1.vbs"

    Shell Perc
End Sub
```

Where `%onedrivecommercial%="C:\Onedrive - Company"`

But it gives error as wscript requires path and filename to be in 8.3 format, while `environ` function is returning it in standard (UNC) format.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way. Looks strange but it works!

Trick is not to get UNC from Environ, but to give UNC path to wscript.

If path is in UNC format wscript wants double quotes around it. It becomes a little bit tricky with VBA but it's ok: you simply have to double the quotes once more.

```
Private Sub Command90_Click()
    Dim Perc As String

    Perc = Environ("onedrivecommercial")
    Perc = "wscript """"""" & Perc & "\DATABA~1\script1.vbs"""""""

    Shell Perc
End Sub
```

I left folder `DATABA~1` in 8.3 format but I also could put in UNC way.